On a mathematical expansion of Burrows Wheelers Transform (BWT) given a transformation of order.
Considering the Burrows Wheelers Transform (BWT) as I have tried to formally describe in an old question of mine.
In this question I will try to expand it in yet another direction.
Consider the possibility that we before ordering define a function to apply to the functions. In other words some kind of a higher ordered order or "transformed" order
$f >_F g$ defined so that $$f >_F g \textrm{ iff } \cases{F(f(i)) = F(g(i)), \forall i < j\\\exists j :F(f(j)) > F(g(j))}$$
$$f = g \textrm{ iff } \nexists j: F(f(j))\neq F(g(j))$$
Given that the BWT is invertible for the assumptions stated in the previous question (please correct me if those are not sufficient!)... as long as we know how $F$ is defined both at encoder and decoder, the permutation / functional performed by the BWT on $F$ shall be invertible simply by taking the BWT:ed function, calculating $F$ and performing iBWT on the permutation given by it.
If this is possible, what requirements would we need to put on $F$?
Will it always be possible regardless of the properties of $F$?
I am of course also interested in any possible references to works which have been done in this area.

Own work :

I have considered strings of unsigned integers of 32 bits width.
I have chosen F to be the function which counts the bit width of the number. For example nr 9 in binary 1001: F(9) = 4, nr 127 1111111 : F(127) = 7

Rewriting the BWT and iBWT from actually moving data around according to the permutation found after F applied to instead returning the index vector of the permutation and applying it does seem to yield an invertible transform at least for an awful many randomized sequences.
But perhaps it is just F which is "nice enough".
If just any F is acceptable which I suspect to be the case, then we should be able to arbitrarily classify the data into bins. Say for example for 8 bit ASCII symbols, we can decide that F be the function which returns 1 for number symbol, 2 for lower case symbol, 3 for upper case symbol, 4 for delimeter, 5 for blank space symbols and so on.
This seems to be such a powerful idea that it should have been done and mentioned before in the literature but from the little window of my tower I cannot see any signs of it. Perhaps I do not know what to search for? What it could be called?
